# Ruby on Rails converts new line \n to \\n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newline

I try save

```
desc += 'SUBJECT: '
desc += '\n'
desc += 'MESSAGE: '
Teme.desc = desc
Teme.save
```

but in the Database I have

```
> Teme.find 190

... desc: "SUBJECT: \\nMESSAGE:
```

Then my textarea show \n instead new line

How safely store new line symbol in database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use double quotes with special characters:

```
desc += 'SUBJECT: '
desc += "\n"
desc += 'MESSAGE: '
Teme.desc = desc
Teme.save
```

`raw desc` or `desc.html_safe` will make the new line

```
> Teme.find 190

... desc: "SUBJECT: \nMESSAGE:
```